# Help with automated renaming in C++

Tags: c++, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Here is my issue:

I have a large library of code where all of the class names begin with Agui. For example:

```
class AguiWidget
{

};

class AguiBitmap
{

};
```

also, all the hpp and cpp files are named like this also:
AguiWidget.hpp

etc.

The library also does not use a namespace.

all of the enums begin and use Agui:
ex:

```
enum AguiKeyEnum
{
   AGUI_KEY_SPACE,
   AGUI_KEY_ENTER
};
```

The include guards also use ex:
AGUI_WIDGET_HPP

So,

My task is to remove all the Agui, AGUI references from the entire project (all the classes and enums), then to encapsulate all the classes into namespace agui.

What would be the easiest way to do this. I also need the hpp and cpp files to no longer have Agui in the filename.

I use MSVC 2008 as an IDE if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to check this thread out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209866/what-visual-studio-add-ins-do-you-use-for-c-refactoring

Comment: You could make a custom script in the language of your choice to do it. It shouldn't take long to put one together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a global find and replace tool. If you have Visual Studio 2008, then it is already built-in. Once you rename all the classes and namespaces, then use another tool to rename the files or build a script to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

As a Linux user (which you aren't, but you could use Cygwin or a separate machine), I'd use the program `sed` to strip the prefixes.  I'd start with this, then review the diffs vs. source control:

```
sed -i 's/Agui//g; s/AGUI_//g' *.hpp *.cpp # and maybe *.sln *.proj
```

Then, renaming the files:

```
for f in *.hpp *.cpp; do mv $f ${f#Agui}; done # or source control's mv
```

Then all that's left is to add namespacing.  You could probably get this done using sed as well, but if the number of files is not huge I'd just do it by hand.  The namespace closing braces are trivial to add though:

```
for f in *.hpp *.cpp; do (echo '} // namespace agui' >> $f); done
```

The opening braces you might want to take a little more care to add, depending on your existing code's structure.

Oh, and look, sed for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm (I haven't used this).

Comment: you may be able to do the same with batch file processing too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either using

cygwin + recursive find + script - use sed for changing names, mv to change files

or figuring how to do the equivalent in powershell.

With the right regular expressions it should work fine.

Make sure to copy the entire directory structure before editing, as it may take a few iterations to debug.